# Model.find({_id:req.body.id}) finds the object but Model.updateOne({_id:req.body.id},{//update}) does not find the the object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
app.post("/admin/editAssignedTask/:id", (req, res) => {
  Task.findById(req.params.id, (err, task) => {
    task.title = req.body.title;
    task.priority = req.body.priority;
    task.date = new Date(req.body.date);
    task.description = req.body.description;
    if (req.body.assignTo) {
      console.log(req.body.assignTo);
      if (typeof req.body.assignTo == "string") {
        task.assignedTo = [...task.assignedTo, req.body.assignTo];
        Staff.find({ _id: req.body.assignTo }, (err, staff) => {
          console.log(staff);
        });
        Staff.updateOne(
          { _id: req.body.assignTo },
          { $set: { $push: { todo: req.params.id } } },
          (err, up) => {
            console.log(up);
          }
        );
```

in the above code staff.find() returns

```
 [ { todo: [ 5cc44b02abde080691893e41, 5cc46186db0195071f117808 ],
 completed: [],
 _id: 5cc34724ab9d2d231642f925,
 name: 'gokul',
 mailId: 'gokul',
 __v: 12 } ]
```

but staff.updateOne() returns
{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }
here n is 0 which means no obects are matched.!
Why does this happen?

below is the Staff schema

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  mailId: String,
  todo: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Task"
    }
  ],
  completed: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Task"
    }
  ]
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

change

```
Staff.updateOne(
  { _id: req.body.assignTo },
  { $set: { $push: { todo: req.params.id } } },
  (err, up) => {
    console.log(up);
  }
);
```

to

```
Staff.updateMany(
  { _id: { $in: req.body.assignTo } },
  { $push: { todo: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) } },
  (err, up) => {
    console.log(up);
  }
);
```

1) don't use $set for pushing or pulling array elements.

2) since in the schema, attribute 'todo' is an array of objectIDs and not strings, we need to explicitly convert the string to objectIDs using mongoose.Types.ObjectId()